# How to target an area within a list using JQuery Ajax?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a form which is a list of fields to be completed by the user. A bit like this:

```
<form>
  <ol>
    <!-- Default form starts -->
    <li>
      <select name="Industry">
          <option value="1">Airlines</option>
          <option value="2">Automotive</option>
          <option value="3">Retail</option>
      </select>
    </li>
    <li>
      <select name="Function">
          <option value="1">Sales</option>
          <option value="2">Accounting</option>
          <option value="3">Consulting</option>
      </select>
    </li>
    <!-- These elements change when the Industry is changed --->
    <li><input type="text" name="ContextAwareInput1" /></li>
    <li><select name="ContextAwareSelect">
          <option value="1">Something</option>
          <option value="2">Anything</option>
          <option value="3">Nothing</option>
      </select>
      </li>
    <li><input type="text" name="ContextAwareInput2" /></li>
    <!-- Back to default form --->
    <li><input type="text" name="Website" /></li>
    <li><input type="text" name="Description" /></li>
    <li><input type="text" name="StartingDate" /></li>
  </ol>
</form>
```

When the `Industry` select option is changed, JQuery will ask the server what HTML content should be presented to the user. I need to remove all the contextaware elements and replace them with the HTML returned from the server. In the real code they do not have anything to distinguish them as context-aware elements.

I thought about wrapping them in a `<div id="ContextAwareArea">` so that I could target that as the element to update e.g. `$('#ContextAwareArea').html(result)`, but I cannot have a `div` inside an `ol` element (its invalid markup).

Would would be the best way to target the area that I need to update? I'm really just looking for a clever way to hook into the DOM at that part and update the HTML. Is there a simpler way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give the `contextAware` elements a class so you can remove them. Add another id to use for insertion point

```
<li class="contextAware"><input type="text" name="ContextAwareInput1" /></li>
<!-- other contextAware <li>'s -->

<li id="afterContextAware"><input type="text" name="Website" /></li>
```

JS

```
$.get(url, function(response){
   $('.contextAware').remove();
   $('#afterContextAware').before(response);
});
```

Then return new set of `<li>` from server

Answer (score 1):

You may achieve this using CSS `counter-increment` and `counter-reset` properties. A little tricky coding with this will enable you to continue your counter even if the list is nested in different containers. For example, I have a HTML like below;

```
  <p>List 1</p>
  <ol class="start">
    <li>abcd</li>
    <li>efgh</li>
  </ol>
  <p>List 2</p>
  <ol class="continue">
    <li>ijkl</li>
  </ol>
  <p>List 3</p>
  <ol class="continue">
    <li>mnop</li>
  </ol>
```

By default, this will create a list like;

```
List 1

    1. abcd
    2. efgh

List 2

    1. ijkl

List 3

    1. mnop
```

But if I apply the css code below;

```
ol li { 
    counter-increment: mycounter; 
}
ol.start { 
    counter-reset: mycounter; 
}
ol li { 
    counter-increment: mycounter;
    list-style-type: none;
}
ol li:before { 
    content: counter(mycounter) ". "; 
}
```

the list will now look like;

```
List 1

    1. abcd
    2. efgh

List 2

    3. ijkl

List 3

    4. mnop
```

Here is a live demo https://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/jkgkrk4t/

Now you can use containers in between. Don't worry about list break. Hope this helps.